# How to translate dynamic content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to translate so dynamic values in a plugin
an example:

```
esc_attr_e( $content['ServiceTypesPage']['headingServices'] );
```

$content can have 2 values

> lets say $content is: 'Hello' es_ES $content should become: 'Hola'
>   pt_BR $ content should become: 'Ola'
>
> let say $content is: 'One' es_ES $content should become: 'Uno' pt_BR $
>   content should become: 'Um'

how could i do that

here is an example from the php

```
<div class="row">
                                            <label for="content[ServiceTypesPage][headingServices]" class="col-md-6 control-label"><?php _e( 'Services Heading', 'calendar-booking' ); ?></label>
                                            <input type="text" name="content[ServiceTypesPage][headingServices]" class="col-md-6" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( $content['ServiceTypesPage']['headingServices'] );?>" />
                                        </div>
                                        <br/>
```

Comment: `printf`, `sprintf`.

Comment: thanks for such a quick reply, im a huge newbie in php could you give me an example if you dong mind